# how to search in json data using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to search in json data on every keyup.

**Json:**

```
{
 "AB01": {
   "foo": "bar",
   "ID": "A1",
   "PID": "Z09",
    },
  "AB10": {
    "foo10": "bar10",
    "ID": "B10",
    "PID": "Y08",
   },
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('input').on('keyup', function(){
  $.getJSON("ABc.json", function(data) {
    var InputVal = $('input').val();
    var myExp = new RegExp(InputVal, "i");

    var results = [];

    $.each(data, function(key, obj){
        if (obj.foo.search(new RegExp(InputVal,"i")) != -1) {
            results.push(obj);
        }       
    });

    for(var i=0; i< $(results).length; i++)
    {
     console.log(JSON.stringify(results[i])); 
    }
  });
});
```

**Html:**

```
<input type="text" name="abc">
```

Now i want that the `input string\char` `on every keyup` match data in json not with `foo` or `ID` but with all key and value.

I can't find how to solve this, any help appreciated.

If any thing you want from my side let me know :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to get the JSON with every key event--cache it instead.

Comment: okay but how to solve my problem..

Comment: Your problem is very badly stated. What your question is really about is traversing object properties, and for that you can use `Object.keys(data)` (see here https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/keys).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do a string comparison on an object.

You need an inner iteration of each property of those objects.

```
$.each(data, function(key, obj){
    var hasMatch = false;
    // use any object property iteration approach to check each value
    $.each(obj, function(key,val){
       if (val.search(new RegExp(InputVal,"i")) != -1) {
          hasMatch = true;
          return false; // break the loop, we have a match
       }  
    });
    if(hasMatch){
       results.push(obj);
    }            
});
```

There are other array methods like filter() you could use but I kept it in same format as your current code

Also note that you should load the data in advance so you don't need to request it each time